# Error during install arulesViz packeg in R in Fedora OS . i have tried this one but no cure(RHadoop - Rstudio - Install arulesViz library)

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, fedora

why I am facing this error in r studio I am using Fedora os

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘igraph’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
    unable to load shared object '/home/mashood/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
    libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Error: loading failed
    Execution halted
    ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/mashood/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/igraph’
    Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status
    ERROR: dependency ‘igraph’ is not available for package ‘arulesViz’
* removing ‘/home/mashood/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/arulesViz’
    Warning in install.packages :
    installation of package ‘arulesViz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The downloaded source packages are in

```
‘/tmp/RtmpxlGnqJ/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: what is the code that you used to install `arulesViz`? What are the repos that you are using?

Comment: install.packeges("arulesViz") this one sir

Comment: i am not using any repos. just this simple command

Comment: seems like it is unable to install `igraph` package. Do you have libxml installed? https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/213 might help. Maybe try to get `igraph` installed first

Comment: Sir  I have just solved this problem by run R as root like sudo R and then I install Rcurl packeg and then I install aruleViz now it works fine :) .